# How to do the sum over integer compositions

Tags: co.combinatorics

How to do summation or how to find another representation of the sum that runs over integer compositions.
$$
 \sum_{r_1+ \ldots + r_{L}=   k}   \left(-\frac{ a}{1+a} \right)^{k-L}   n^{(3 r_1)} (n+3 r_{1}-1)^{(3 r_{2})}\cdot \ldots \cdot (n+\sum_{i=1}^{L-1} 3 r_i- L+1)^{(3 r_{L})} 
$$
where $\sum r_i = k$ runs over all integer   compositions of $k$ and  $L$ is a number of parts in the composition and $n^{(3 r_1)}$ is the rising factorial. $n$ is a positive integer or zero. I mean usual definition of  compositions as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics).

Realization in Mathematica may  become somehow  useful

```
Sum[(-(a/(1 + a)))^(p - r) Product[Pochhammer[n + Plus@@Table[3 k[[i]]-1, {i, 1, j - 1}],3 k[[j]]],{j, 1, r}],{r, 1, p},{k,Compositions[p-r,r]+1}]
```

Comment: According to your formula $L=k-1$. Do you mean that some of the $r_i$ are zero and $L$ is the number of nonzero ones?

Comment: is $n^{(3)}:=n(n+1)(n+2)$ or $n(n-1)(n-2)$ ?

Comment: If all $r_i$ are non zero shouldn't they all be equal to $1$ to sum to $k-1$? is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: $ n^{(3)}=n(n+1)(n+2)$ is right one. I mean only rising factorials.

Comment: No, I did not. Restriction is  $\sum r_i = (k-1)$. But $n$  is any positive  integer or zero.

Comment: so e.g. for k-1=3 there are ten triples $(r_1,r_2,r_3)$ that is $(0,0,3),(0,1,2),(0,2,1),\dots,(3,0,0)$ , is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself twice. Compositions is not a weak composition. But some $k_i$ might be a zero. For k-1 =3 we have  a set: $(1,1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (3)$. It is a usual composition not as that I used in Mathematica.

Comment: Please clean up your question. The relation between $k$, $L$ and $r_1,\ldots,r_k$ is unclear, and you have undefined quanties $r(1)$ and $k_i$. Put the definitions in the question, not just in the comments.

Comment: @brendan-mckay  I changed the detail of the task so definition become more clear. Please, put more concrete  question .

Comment: Your Mathematica code contains an unmatched left parenthesis. PLEASE concentrate on what you are doing.

Comment: Your `HeavisideTheta[j - 1/2]` is always $1$ since your `j` is always a natural number

Comment: @max-alekseyev Yes, you are right. I changed definition and formula.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes. I corrected  the code.

Comment: The unmatched left parenthesis is still there. I guess you have to remove the very first parenthesis in the code. Did you try to run it? How did you check that it gives you the expected results if it does not run?

Comment: Does this look as it should?$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 6 & \frac{360 (1-a)}{a+1} & \frac{15120 (5 a^2-14 a+5)}{(a+1)^2} & \frac{5443200 (1-a) (7 a^2-30 a+7)}{(a+1)^3} \\
 24 & \frac{720 (4-3 a)}{a+1} & \frac{120960 (5 a^2-17 a+8)}{(a+1)^2} & \frac{10886400(-35 a^3+214 a^2-259 a+64)}{(a+1)^3} \\
 60 & \frac{2520 (5-3 a)}{a+1} & \frac{907200(3 a^2-12 a+7)}{(a+1)^2} & \frac{59875200(-35 a^3+243 a^2-345 a+105)}{(a+1)^3} \\
 120 & \frac{20160 (2-a)}{a+1} & \frac{1814400(5 a^2-23 a+16)}{(a+1)^2} & \frac{239500800(-35 a^3+272 a^2-443 a+160)}{(a+1)^3} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Yes, I fixed this. Your result is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be fixed.

The sum in question can rewritten as
$$S_k:=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{L=1}^k\sum_{r_1+\dots+r_L=k} (n+3k-L)!\cdot \alpha^{k-L}\cdot f(n,k,L),$$
where $\alpha:=-\frac{a}{a+1}$ and
$$f(n,k,L) := \sum_{0<s_1<\dots<s_{L-1}<k}\ \prod_{i=1}^{L-1} (n+3s_i-i).$$
(think of $s_i = r_1+\dots+r_i$)

This function for $L>1$ satisfies the recurrence:
$$f(n,k,L) = \sum_{t=1}^{k-1} f(n,t,L-1)\cdot (n+3t-L+1).$$
For the generating function
$$F(x,y) := \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{L=1}^k f(n,k,L) x^k y^{n+3k-L}$$
it implies a linear differential equation:
$$F(x,y) = \frac{xy^3}{1-xy^3}F'_y(x,y)+\frac{y^{n+2}x}{1-xy^3}$$
with a [known solution](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0103.pdf).

Going back to the original sum, we apply Laplace transform to derive:

$$S_k = \frac{1}{(n-1)!\alpha^n}\ [x^k] \int_0^\infty F\big(\frac{x}{\alpha^2}, \alpha t\big) e^{-t} {\rm d}t,$$
where $[x^k]$ is the operator taking the coefficient of $x^k$.

I did not try much to simplify the result, but it gives a closed form expression for (the generating function of) $S_k$ nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you for this algebra, it is very impressive, but I need other thing. I start from differential equation and after solving it I  obtain discret partial   equation. Half of its solution I presented here. But my goal is in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402164/how-to-do-the-sum-after-sum-over-integer-compositions .