# How to explicitly obtain an analytic function whose power series coefficients are sums over integer compositions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, power-series, closed-form-expressions

Starting with the following differential equation,
\begin{eqnarray}
 x \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} P[h, x] -  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial h^2} \left( h \frac{\partial}{\partial h}  P [h, x] \right) + \frac{x}{1+x} = 0 \ .
 \label{equation_for_Px}
\end{eqnarray}
and substituting expression
$$
P[h, x]= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Omega (k, n ) h^{2k} (x-a)^n
$$ in it, I obtained the following discrete partial equation for  $\Omega (k, n )$:
$$
\begin{split}
\Omega(k+1,n) &= \frac{1}{4 (2 k+1) (k+1)^2 } \bigg[\delta_{k,0} \left.\Big(\frac{x}{1+x}\Big)^{(n)}  \right|_{x=a}  + \\
 & \qquad+ (n+1) (n+2)\big(n  \Omega(k,n+2)+ a  (n+3)\Omega(k,n+3)\big) \bigg]
\end{split}
$$
where the start conditions are
$$
\begin{cases}
\Omega (0, n )=0\\
\Omega (1, n )=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{a}{4 (1 + a)}&\text{for }n=0\\
\dfrac{1}{4} \left.\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^{(n)} \right |_{x=a} = \dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{-1}{1 + a}\right)^{1 + n} &\text{for }n>0
\end{cases} 
\end{cases}.
$$
This recurrence can be exactly solved as
$$
\begin{split}
\Omega(k,n) & = \frac{ \left(-\dfrac{1}{1+a}\right)^{n+2k-1} }{2^k (2 k+1)! k! } \Bigg[ \sum_{r(1)+ \ldots + r(L-1)=   (k-1)} \bigg(-\frac{ a}{1+a} \bigg)^{k-1-L} \cdot\\
 & \quad\cdot  n^{(3 r(1))} (n+3 r(1)-1)^{(3 r(2))}\cdot \ldots \cdot \left(n+\sum_{i=1}^{L-2} 3 r(i)- L+2\right)^{(3 r(L- 1))} \\
&\quad\quad + \left(-\frac{ a}{1+a} \right) \{n \rightarrow n+1 \} \Bigg] .
\end{split}\label{equ5tyfyt}
$$
where $\sum r_i = (k-1)$ runs over all integer compositions of  $(k- 1)$,  $L$ is a number of parts of this  composition and $n^{(3 r(1))}$ is a rising factorial.

I need to obtain the explicit sum of following power series, if possible:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Omega (k, n ) h^{2k}
$$

Comment: For $x=a$ you get from your equation that $6a\sum_{k=1}^\infty\Omega(k,3)h^{2k}=-\frac a{1+a}$, is this possible at all for $a\ne0$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე OK I fixed this, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you refer to [A336110](https://oeis.org/A336110)? It contains important additional information provided by Jean-François Alcover

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე This sequence is created (and discovered) by me and my colleagues. Thank you for ref  :)

Comment: $$\Omega(k, m) = \frac{12^k}{(1+k)!(2k+1)!} \prod_{L=1..k} \binom{m+2L}{ 3}$$ is core of solution in the  form $\sum_{k=0}\sum_{m=1} \Omega(k, m) h^{2k+2} x^{m}$

Comment: That one solves $4xu_{xxx}=hu_{hhh}$. Do you mean you can construct a solution of your equation from it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე This is solution of the same equation 
$$ x \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} P[h, x] -  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial h^2} \left( h \frac{\partial}{\partial h}  P [h, x] \right) + \frac{x}{1+x} = 0 \ .
$$

Comment: Are you sure? I obtain $P(h,x)=h^2x+h^2x^2+h^4x+h^2x^3+4h^4x^2+h^2x^4+2h^6x+10h^4x^3+h^2x^5+...$ and when I substitute this into the left hand side of the equation I get $-3x-5x^2-3x^3-42h^2x-5x^4-168h^2x^2-3x^5-420h^2x^3-300h^4x-...$ instead of zero.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I forget that instead of $h$ I have $h/2$ in this case. Substitution is $$
P[h, x]= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Omega (k, n ) (\frac{h}{2})^{2k+2} x^n
$$

Comment: Sorry, I still fail to obtain a solution. This time I get $P(h,x)=h^2x/4+h^2x^2/4+h^4x/16+h^2x^3/4+h^4x^2/4+h^2x^4/4+h^6x/32+5h^4x^3/8+h^2x^5/4+...$ Substituting this into the left hand side I get $-2x^2-3h^2x/2-2x^4-6h^2x^2-15h^2x^3-15h^4x/8-...$

Comment: Yes. sorry I forget one more ingredient.$$
P[h, x]= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\Omega (k, n )}{1+k} (\frac{h}{2})^{2k+2} x^n
$$ I used sometimes different definitions.

Comment: Aha this works, thank you!

Comment: So the coefficient at $h^{2k+2}x^n$ is$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{8(k+1)!(k+1)}\binom{n+2k}{n-1}\left(\frac n2+1\right)^{(k-1)}$$